# Converting java.sql.Timestamp to StringNode when passing map to Jackon's valueToTree method

Tags: java, sql, jackson

I have a map `Map<String, Object>` and some values are of type `java.sql.Timestamp`. I want to create a JSON node object using Jackson that would convert `java.sql.Timestamp` to `StringNode` node using method `valueToTree`. Using default `ObjectMapper`, `java.sql.Timestamp` is converted `LongNode`.

Comment: That's because the timestamp is interpreted as an instant in milliseconds, most likely... Try to convert it to an actual `Instant` or a `LocalDateTime`, maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend [JsonSerializer class](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer.html), for a specific type and include that in the mapper via Module

```html
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(TimeStamp.class, new TimeStampSerializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);
```

APIs might differ based on the version being used.